# How to locate all the configuration classes under a package and store a instance of each in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader

I'm trying to figure out how to load all the configuration classes under a package and save it to a map. That map will be passed into other services to get their configurations. Each package is a different environment and each configuration class pulls from a different yml file.

This seems like an area that reflection could be useful. Grab the classes from under the package and create a new instance of each and save it to a map. It was suggested that I take a look at java classLoaders. I am new to reflection and classloaders.

(application structure)

```
src/main/java/com.example.demo
|
-- configs
|     - KConfigurations
|
-- properties
|    - dev
|       - A1DevProperty
|       - B1DevProperty
|    - PropertyConfig
|
-- DemoApplication
|
-- resources
      - application.yml
      - application-a1-dev.yml
      - application-b1-dev.yml
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application: test-application
  profiles:
    include:
      - a1-dev
      - b1-dev
```

application-a1.yml

```
a1-dev:
  evn: dev
  name: testing-a1-dev
```

./poperties/PropertyConfig (base class)

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfig {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PropertyConfig{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

./poperties/dev/A1DevProperty

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "a1-dev")
public class A1DevProperty extends PropertyConfig {

}
```

./configs/KConfigurations

```
@Component
public class KConfigurations {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KConfigurations.class);
    Map<String, PropertyConfig> kConfigurations;
    List<Class> myProperties;
    Reflections reflections;

    public KConfigurations() {
        this(new HashMap<String, PropertyConfig>(), new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public KConfigurations(Map<String, PropertyConfig> kConfigurations,  List<Class> myProperties) {
        this.kConfigurations = kConfigurations;
        this.myProperties = myProperties;
        this.reflections = new Reflections("com.example.demo.properties.dev");
    }

    public String loadKConfigurations(){
        for(String propertyName :reflections.getStore().get(SubTypesScanner.class.getSimpleName()).values()){
            try {
                myProperties.add(Class.forName(propertyName));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        LOG.info("Property Name : {}", myProperties.toString());
        LOG.info("Property type : {}", myProperties.get(0).getCanonicalName());

        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        try {
            Class loadedMyClass = classLoader.loadClass(myProperties.get(0).getCanonicalName());
            LOG.info("Load class name : {}", loadedMyClass.getName());

            Constructor constructor = loadedMyClass.getConstructor();
            PropertyConfig myClassObject = (PropertyConfig)constructor.newInstance();
            LOG.info(myClassObject.toString());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "done";
    }
}
```

Expected,
After running the code, the configuration class will be created and had pulled the properties from the yml file.

Actual,
The class is created, but the properties file is not read into the configuration class. The getName property returns null.

Output from logs:

```
LOG.info("Property Name : {}", myProperties.toString());
Property Name : [class com.example.demo.properties.dev.A1DevProperty, class com.example.demo.properties.dev.B1DevProperty]
-----
LOG.info("Property type : {}", myProperties.get(0).getCanonicalName());
Property type : com.example.demo.properties.dev.A1DevProperty
-----
LOG.info("Load class name : {}", loadedMyClass.getName());
Load class name : com.example.demo.properties.dev.A1DevProperty
-----

LOG.info(myClassObject.toString());
PropertyConfig{name='null'}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Is there a better way to do this task or any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what's going on here. It looks like you're trying to reinvent auto-configuration itself; please explain what you're trying to do that is different from just writing your own `spring.factories`. (Configuration classes can, among other things, add extra property sources to the context's resolver.)

Comment: Is the properties file named application-a1-dev.yml or application-a1.yml?

Comment: @chrylis I have to call an external rest service to create part of our env for our own services. Each env has different requirements. So basically, get all the properties for that env and create a number of batch jobs to a rest service.

Comment: @Strelok The a1 properties for dev is named application-a1-dev.yml under the resource folder and referenced by A1DevProperty.class to load those configurations.